# Need to convert rows into columns with sort

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to convert rows into columns but include a sort of the data.

Sample Data
For instance:

```
+-----+------+------+
| CId | Cat1 | cat2 |
+-----+------+------+
|   1 |   10 |    6 |
|   1 |  230 |  100 |
|   2 | 1222 |   30 |
|   3 |    2 |   50 |
|   4 |   33 |   21 |
|   1 |   33 |   13 |
+-----+------+------+
```

Expected output

```
+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| CId | Rw1  | Rw2 | Rw3 | Rw4 | Rw5 | Rw6 |
+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   1 |   10 |  33 | 230 |   6 |  13 | 100 |
|   2 | 1222 |  30 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|   3 |    2 |  50 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|   4 |   33 |  21 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

See how `CID: 1` sorted all values for `Cat1` after that's done, need to sort `cat2` and everything should be in one row.

Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Will you always only have a total of 6 final columns?  Or will the number of columns be unknown?

Comment: I'll have around 10 columns and ready to manual key in column name if necessary

Answer (score 3):

You can get the result by unpivoting and pivoting the data, but you will also want to use `row_number()` to keep the data in the sequence that you want.

First step would be to query your current data and apply a `row_number()` to get a value for each row, partitioned by the `cid` and ordered by `cat1` and `cat2`:

```
select cid, cat1, cat2,
  row_number() over(partition by cid order by cat1, cat2) seq
from yourtable
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62fd3/1). Once you have the data, then you will unpivot the multiple columns `cat1` and `cat2` into a single column with multiple rows. You can use the UNPIVOT function or you can use CROSS APPLY to convert the data:

```
select cid, value
  , 'rw'+cast(row_number() over(partition by cid order by col, seq) as varchar(10)) rw
from 
(
  select cid, cat1, cat2,
    row_number() over(partition by cid order by cat1, cat2) seq
  from yourtable
) d
cross apply
(
  select 1, cat1 union all
  select 2, cat2
) c (col, value)
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62fd3/15). When you unpivot the data, you will apply the `row_number()` a second time, this will be used to create your new columns names.  When applied this time, you will partition the data by the `cid` and order it by your columns `cat1`/`cat2` (I used `1`/`2`) as well as the sequence you original created. This new row number will create all of the new column headers and it will keep the data in the order that you want to display it in.

Finally you will apply the PIVOT function:

```
select cid,
  coalesce(rw1, 0) rw1, 
  coalesce(rw2, 0) rw2, 
  coalesce(rw3, 0) rw3, 
  coalesce(rw4, 0) rw4, 
  coalesce(rw5, 0) rw5, 
  coalesce(rw6, 0) rw6
from 
(
  select cid, value
    , 'rw'+cast(row_number() over(partition by cid order by col, seq) as varchar(10)) rw
  from 
  (
    select cid, cat1, cat2,
      row_number() over(partition by cid order by cat1, cat2) seq
    from yourtable
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    select 1, cat1 union all
    select 2, cat2
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for rw in (rw1, rw2, rw3, rw4, rw5, rw6)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62fd3/16). This gives a final result:

```
| CID |  RW1 | RW2 | RW3 | RW4 | RW5 | RW6 |
|-----|------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|   1 |   10 |  33 | 230 |   6 |  13 | 100 |
|   2 | 1222 |  30 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|   3 |    2 |  50 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|   4 |   33 |  21 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
```